Is the matrix formed by taking the absolute values of the elements of a positive-definite covariance matrix still positive definite?
Suppose I have a positive-definite covariance matrix $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$. I construct a new matrix $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}$, where each element $(i,j)$ in $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}$ is equal to the absolute value of the corresponding element in $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$. Is $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}$ still a valid covariance matrix?
and if not, under which condition it is true?

Did you simulate it with some matrices already? What is the outcome for 10000 different matrices? Is there strong indication or did you find a counter example? You can construct arbitrary covariance matrices by specifying them in their eigenspace (in diagonal form and then rotating them to other bases by applying rotation matrices left and right) ... My intuition tells me that taking the abs does not always go well ...

@Ggjj11 I warmly recommend, then, performing the simulation you suggested, because it will improve your intuition!

@Ggjj11 I ran a simulation earlier and didn’t encounter any violations, even after many iterations. However, when I ran it again, the matrix frequently turned out to be non-positive definite. I’m not sure if I made a mistake before or if I’m making one now. Here’s my R code:
library(MCMCpack)
ss = riwish(12, diag(1,10))
chol(ss)
chol(abs(ss))

Asked&answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1355088/is-the-absolute-value-of-a-p-d-s-matrix-p-d-s, summary: true for $n=2,3$ but not for larger dimension

It's too bad that all the analytical insight in that question is contained in the comments (it would be nice to see @Wintermute explain further how/why "Gershgorin's circle theorem provides the insite [sic]" as to why the conjecture is true for $d \le 3$ and false for $d>3$ ...)

So, first, simulation
> r<-replicate(1000,{
+ ss = riwish(12, diag(1,10)) 
+ sum(eigen(abs(ss))$values< -1e-3)
+ })
> table(r)
r
  0   1   2   3 
519 431  49   1 

The other thing you learn from simulation is by varying the dimension: it's easy to get counterexamples for $n>3$ but not for $n\leq 3$.
Clearly it's true for $n=1$.  It's also easy to see for $n=2$ that the only constraint on positive-definiteness for a real symmetric matrix is that the single off-diagonal correlation is in $(-1,1)$, so it's true for $n=2$.
Unfortunately it's harder to think about $n=3$, and much harder for larger $n$ to understand what fails in the general case.  However, I don't think it's surprising that it fails -- I don't see any reason to expect it to be true

+1.  For constructing counterexamples it's a nice idea to find "simple" ones.  In this case, that would mean with as small a dimension as possible and with small integral values.  You can do this by rounding ss (and checking that it remains positive definite).  With this method, for instance, I find this remarkable counterexample: $$\pmatrix{5&1&0&4\1&2&1&0\0&1&3&-1\4&0&-1&4}.$$
